# How do Panharmonicon effects work with replacement effects?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, replacement-effect

If I have [Kalitas, Traitor of Ghet](https://scryfall.com/card/ogw/86/kalitas-traitor-of-ghet) and [Drivnod, Carnage Dominus](https://scryfall.com/card/one/90/drivnod-carnage-dominus) in play at the same time, and a creature controlled by an opponent dies, do I get 2 zombies off of Kalitas or only 1?

At first I thought 2, but now I think kalitas actually prevents Drivnod from trigger since the creature didn't actually die...

Does this have implications for other panharmonicon style affects? Or is this kind of thing limited to the dies scenario (since dying means it has to actually hit the graveyard)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only get one zombie, because Kalitas's ability is a replacement effect, not a triggered ability, so it has no direct interaction with Drivnod's ability. And since the original creature no longer dies, no abilities that trigger when a creature dies will trigger, so there's nothing for Drivnod to interact with there either.

If a replacement effect modifies an event, then that original event doesn't happen. If a triggered ability would trigger from the original event but not the modified event, then it doesn't trigger, which means that there's nothing for Panharmonicon or Drivnod or any similar effect to see and interact with.

Comment: Does this mean that a replacement effect is just categorically not a triggered ability? For instance, is it technically wrong to say the creature dying "triggers" Kalitas?

Comment: Yes, they're entirely different things. Triggered abilities are defined in [rules section 603](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Triggered_ability) and replacement effects are defined in [rules section 614](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Replacement_effect).